# octave installed error - Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2)

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, 64-bit

i read all this article and search but my problem not solve

i install `ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS`

```
$sudo apt-get install octave
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 octave : Depends: libarpack2 (>= 2.1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libcholmod3.0.6 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: liboctave3 (= 4.0.0-3ubuntu9) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: libopenblas-base but it is not going to be installed or
                      libatlas3-base but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and with `aptitute`:

```
$sudo aptitude install octave
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aglfn{a} ca-certificates-java{a} default-jre-headless{a} gnuplot-data{a} gnuplot-tex{a} gnuplot-x11{a} java-common{a} 
  libaec0{a} libamd2.4.1{a} libarpack2{a} libblas-common{a} libblas3{a} libcamd2.4.1{a} libccolamd2.9.1{a} libcholmod3.0.6{a} 
  libcxsparse3.1.4{a} libfltk-gl1.3{a} libfltk1.3{a} libgfortran3{ab} libgl2ps0{a} libglpk36{a} libgraphicsmagick++-q16-12{a} 
  libgraphicsmagick-q16-3{a} libhdf5-10{a} libjasper1{a} liblapack3{a} liblua5.1-0{a} libmagick++-6.q16-5v5{a} libmng2{a} 
  libmysqlclient20{a} liboctave3{a} libopenblas-base{a} libosmesa6{a} libplot2c2{a} libpstoedit0c2a{a} libqhull7{a} 
  libqrupdate1{a} libqscintilla2-12v5{a} libqscintilla2-l10n{a} libqt4-dbus{a} libqt4-declarative{a} libqt4-network{a} 
  libqt4-opengl{a} libqt4-script{a} libqt4-sql{a} libqt4-sql-mysql{a} libqt4-xml{a} libqt4-xmlpatterns{a} libqtcore4{a} 
  libqtdbus4{a} libqtgui4{a} libsz2{a} libtext-unidecode-perl{a} libumfpack5.7.1{a} libxml-libxml-perl{a} 
  libxml-namespacesupport-perl{a} libxml-sax-base-perl{a} libxml-sax-expat-perl{a} libxml-sax-perl{a} mysql-common{a} octave 
  octave-common{a} openjdk-8-jre-headless{a} pstoedit{a} qdbus{a} qt-at-spi{a} qtchooser{a} qtcore4-l10n{a} tex-common{a} 
  texinfo{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 70 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 66.2 MB of archives. After unpacking 283 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgfortran3 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)      libarpack2 [Not Installed]                         
2)      libcholmod3.0.6 [Not Installed]                    
3)      libgfortran3 [Not Installed]                       
4)      libhdf5-10 [Not Installed]                         
5)      liblapack3 [Not Installed]                         
6)      liboctave3 [Not Installed]                         
7)      libopenblas-base [Not Installed]                   
8)      libqrupdate1 [Not Installed]                       
9)      libumfpack5.7.1 [Not Installed]                    
10)     octave [Not Installed]                             

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:         
11)     octave recommends libopenblas-base | libatlas3-base
```

this line show when i want install another package:

```
Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1 is installed.
```

for example for `g++`:

```
$ sudo apt install g++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 g++ : Depends: g++-5 (>= 5.3.1-3~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

i set repo to main ubunu site and run `apt-get update` but not solve

i run `apt-get update` , `apt-get upgrade` , `aptget -f install` ,

and ... but not solve problem

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt -f install` then `sudo apt upgrade` then `sudo apt install octave`.

Comment: not solve http://pastebin.com/F0zWXpgH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run `sudo aptitude octave` and install downgrade package

version `gcc-5-base 5.4.0` installed on system but i downgrade it to `gcc-5-base 5.3.1`

i run this command `sudo aptitude octave` and in command prompt i typed `.` then press `enter` to show next resolve for downgrade. then i accept resolve with type `Y` . `gcc-5-base` package downgraded and `octave` installed and system isn't any problem..