# Unable to install mysql-workbench for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: package-management, dpkg, mysql, dependencies, mysql-workbench

I looked around the several answer but none solved my problem.
First, I tried `sudo apt install mysql-workbench -f`.

It shows

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  mysql-workbench :
Depends: libgdal.so.1-1.11.3
                   Depends: libgdal1i (>= 1.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: mysql-utilities but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
packages.
```

If I tried to install `libgdal1i`, it will show

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libgdal1i : Depends:
libarmadillo6 but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libhdf5-10 but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libnetcdf11 (>= 4.0.1) but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

There is no end of this story. I tried to install a dep but it always tell me another dep is lack and need to be installed.
Besides, I don't know why it says `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken`. I checked in `synaptic`->`custom filters`->`broken`, nothing is there.

Also, I tried `sudo aptitude install mysql-workbench -f` since other posts said `aptitude` is better.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libgfortran3 :
Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1 is
installed.  mysql-connector-python : Conflicts: python-mysql.connector
but 2.0.4-1 is to be installed. The following actions will resolve
these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version: 
1)      libarmadillo6 [Not Installed]   
2)      libarpack2> [Not Installed]   
3)      libgdal1i [Not Installed]
4)      libgfortran3 [Not Installed] 
5)      libhdf5-10 [Not Installed]  
6)      liblapack3 [Not Installed]                        
7)      libnetcdf11 [Not Installed]
8)      mysql-connector-python [Not Installed]
9)      mysql-utilities [Not Installed]
10)     mysql-workbench [Not Installed]                    



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]  No packages will be installed,
upgraded, or removed. 0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to
remove and 0 not to upgrade. Need to get 0 B of archives. After
unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

I accepted the solution by type `enter`, as you can see the issue is not solved.

In the last, I tried to download `.deb` from official site and install. No luck and the similar errors are prompted.

By inputting `apt-cache policy mysql-workbench libgdal1i gcc-5-base libhdf5-10`, it displays:

```
mysql-workbench:   
   Installed: (none)
   Candidate: 6.3.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1  Version table:
         6.3.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
            500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages 

libgdal1i:   
   Installed: (none)
   Candidate:    1.11.3+dfsg-3build2
   Version table:
         1.11.3+dfsg-3build2 500
            500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages 

gcc-5-base:
   Installed: 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1
   Candidate: 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1
   Version table:
  *** 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1 100
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
         5.3.1-14ubuntu2 500
            500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages 

libhdf5-10:
   Installed: (none)
   Candidate:  1.8.16+docs-4ubuntu1
   Version table:
         1.8.16+docs-4ubuntu1 500
            500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

The result of `apt-cache policy libgfortran3 libarmadillo6 libnetcdf11 python-mysql.connector` is

`libgfortran3:
  Installed: 5.3.1-14ubuntu2
  Candidate: 5.3.1-14ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libarmadillo6:
  Installed: 1:6.500.5+dfsg-1
  Candidate: 1:6.500.5+dfsg-1
  Version table:
 *** 1:6.500.5+dfsg-1 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libnetcdf11:
  Installed: 1:4.4.0-2
  Candidate: 1:4.4.0-2
  Version table:
 *** 1:4.4.0-2 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
python-mysql.connector:
  Installed: 2.0.4-1
  Candidate: 2.0.4-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.0.4-1 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

The result of `grep -v ^# -r /etc/apt/sources.list etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` is:

`/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list:deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ xenial mysql-apt-config
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list:deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ xenial mysql-5.7
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list:deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ xenial mysql-tools
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list:deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ xenial mysql-5.7
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/slack.list:deb https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian/ jessie main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/`

Comment: On clean xenial it installs normally. Do you have PPA or third-party repositories? Please add to your question the following: output of `apt-cache policy mysql-workbench libgdal1i  gcc-5-base libhdf5-10`.

Comment: @N0rbert, thanks for your response. I've updated the result.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libgfortran3 libarmadillo6 libnetcdf11 python-mysql.connector` and `grep -v ^# -r /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` (to show enabled sources).

Comment: @N0rbert, thanks for your suggestion. I am curious too. Kindly review my updated output.

Comment: It seems that you missed `xenial-updates` and `xenial-security` sections. I'll update my answer.

Comment: True. I suspect the problem is caused because I untick all the checkboxes in `Updates` tab of `Software & Updates`. However, I reinstall the OS with a clean Ubuntu. Everything works great. I cannot retry the solution. Sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to run `sudo apt-get update` before installing MySQL Workbench (Australian mirror is synced normally, it has correct version of [gcc-5-base in pool](http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/)).

If it does not help, try to switch to *Main server* (*Software & Updates* or `software-properties-gtk`, *Ubuntu Software* tab, set *Download from* to *Main server*).

For sure add all official repositories with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
```

Make sure you have enabled `xenial-updates` and `xenial-security` sections:

1. open `software-properties-gtk`
2. go to *Updates* tab
3. check first two checkboxes - `(xenial-updates)` and `(xenial-security)`
4. enter password, click *Authenticate*
5. click *Close*, then *Reload* and wait it to finish.

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

Comment: I switched to `main server` as you suggested, and do everything as you said. It still said `libgdal.so.1-1.11.3` and `libgdal1i (>= 1.8.0)` depends are lacking. Exactly as before. Actually, I always do `sudo apt-get update` first.

Comment: Very strange. Try to install all updates with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and retry.

Comment: I have tried this before. And no diff.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for `aptitude`. Finally I worked it out after referring to [octave installed error - Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/853904/octave-installed-error-depends-gcc-5-base-5-3-1-14ubuntu2) . `aptitude` will propose multiple solutions after you continuously input `n`. Choose the one with the downgrade packages. Everything works as charming.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgfortran3 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1 is installed.
 mysql-connector-python : Conflicts: python-mysql.connector but 2.0.4-1 is to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

```
  Keep the following packages at their current version:
```

1)      libarmadillo6 [Not Installed]
2)      libarpack2 [Not Installed]
3)      libgdal1i [Not Installed]
4)      libgfortran3 [Not Installed]
5)      libhdf5-10 [Not Installed]
6)      liblapack3 [Not Installed]
7)      libnetcdf11 [Not Installed]
8)      mysql-connector-python [Not Installed]
9)      mysql-utilities [Not Installed]
10)     mysql-workbench [Not Installed]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

```
 Keep the following packages at their current version:
```

1)     libarmadillo6 [Not Installed]
2)     libarpack2 [Not Installed]
3)     libgdal1i [Not Installed]
4)     libgfortran3 [Not Installed]
5)     libhdf5-10 [Not Installed]
6)     liblapack3 [Not Installed]
7)     libnetcdf11 [Not Installed]
8)     mysql-workbench [Not Installed]
9)     python-mysql.connector [Not Installed]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

```
  Remove the following packages:
```

1)      build-essential
2)      g++
3)      g++-5
4)      gcc
5)      gcc-5
6)      libasan2
7)      libatomic1
8)      libcilkrts5
9)      libgcc-5-dev
10)     libitm1
11)     liblsan0
12)     libmpx0
13)     libstdc++-5-dev
14)     libtsan0
15)     libubsan0

```
  Install the following packages:
```

16)     mysql-utilities [1.6.1-2 (xenial)]
17)     tcc [0.9.27~git20151227.933c223-1 (xenial)]

```
  Keep the following packages at their current version:
```

18)     mysql-connector-python [Not Installed]

```
  Downgrade the following packages:
```

19)     cpp-5 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]
20)     gcc-5-base [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]
21)     libcc1-0 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]
22)     libgomp1 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]
23)     libquadmath0 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]
24)     libstdc++6 [5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1 (now) -> 5.3.1-14ubuntu2 (xenial)]

```
  Leave the following dependencies unresolved:
```

25)     dpkg-dev recommends build-essential

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] 
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  cpp-5 gcc-5-base libcc1-0 libgomp1 libquadmath0 libstdc++6

Answer (score 0):

on Ubuntu 19

1)I had to preceding it on Ubuntu 19 also install manually a library libzip https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.10/ubuntu-universe-amd64/libzip4_1.1.2-1.1_amd64.deb.html

2) then manually selecting on download page deb package for mysql workbench https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

then install deb packages via standard apt installer in Downloads dir

`sudo apt install ./libzip4_1.1.2-1.1_amd64.deb`

and downloaded workbench deb package

`sudo apt install ./mysql-workbench-community_8.0.16-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb`

Answer (score 0):

For me it was simply running `sudo apt-get upgrade` after the `sudo apt-get update` command before installing my packages. 
Leaving it here for people that might run into the same problem in the future!